# Why does Vala print stderr.printf before stdout.printf even though the later is first in the code?

Tags: vala

This is kind of a weird behavior. Basically, I have this code:

```
stdout.printf("Enter some random number: ");
int number = int.parse(stdin.read_line());
stdout.printf(number.to_string());
stderr.printf("THIS IS AN ERROR!\n");
```

Now what's weird to me is that when I compile and run this code, I get this output:

```
Enter some random number: 2
THIS IS AN ERROR!
2user@host:...
```

But if I add a line that says `stdout.printf("\n");` between the last two commands, I get this as in input:

```
Enter some random number: 2
2
THIS IS AN ERROR!
user@host
```

Why is this happening? Why is Vala outputting the number *after* the `sterr.printf()` output in the first example and *before* in the second one? Shouldn't it just print `2THIS IS AN ERROR!` in the first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vala is just using C's `fprintf` underneath, which displays these semantics. Have a look at [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

You can call [`stdout.flush()`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.FileStream.flush) if you want.

Comment: Also there are deeper mechanisms of how the terminal works that surface here. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Modes for a discussion of "line-at-a-time mode" and how this is done in POSIX.-